# Segregating list by attribute

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

We have a List of  Students belonging to various grades - `List<Student>`.

```
Student {

    String name;
    ..........
    ..........
    String grade;

}
```

While processing the list ,it has to be segregated into grades.
The final output of the method will be a list of Grades - Grade being as below:

```
Grade{
    String grade;
    List<Student> students;
}
```

The current approach will be to build an intermediate map `Map<String,List<student>>`,by iterating students.
Then,convert the intermediate map to a list by creating Grade instances from the Map.
Is there a better way - involving lesser iterations,given that the numbers of students will be in thousands.

The return type is not an option - and we are on Java 8.

Comment: are you not simply looking to `groupBy` with `grade` attribute instead of the name? and then your key and value pair would compose the `Grade` instance.

Comment: If things does not work, then tell us. simply posting question and going to vacation is not good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think use of `toMap()` collector with merger function is better.

```
List<Grade> grades = new ArrayList<>(list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors
           .toMap(Student::getGrade, YOUR_CLASS::value, YOUR_CLASS::merge)).values());
```

and

```
private static Grade value(Student s) {
    return new Grade(s.getGrade(), new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(s)));
}

private static Grade merge(Grade g1, Grade g2) {
    g1.getStudents().addAll(g2.getStudents());
    return g1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a constructor like this:

```
public Grade(String grade, List<Student> students){}
```

You can `groupBy` a stream and map each grade/list pair into a `Grade` object:

```
List<Grade> grades = students.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade), 
                  map -> map.entrySet()
                          .stream()
                          .map(e -> new Grade(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
                          .collect(Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: why not use like : `Map<String, List<Student>> collect = sList.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade));` ?

Comment: Well, that will work, except that it won't create `Grade` instances.

Answer (score 1):

I find this rather very simple:

```
Map<String, List<Student>> collect = sList.stream()
                                    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getGrade));
```

After above step you have `Map<String, List<Student>>` and as per your question you want to step further and convert `Map<String, List<Student>>` to `List<Grade>` which ideally should have constructor like :

```
  public Grade(String grade, List<Student> students) {
    this.grade = grade;
    this.students = students;
  }
```

Now, converting `Map<String, List<Student>>` to `List<Grade>` :

```
List<Grade> gList = collect.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map(m -> new Grade(m.getKey(), m.getValue()))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```